# Deleting all content between brackets from a string using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am using beautiful soup to grab data from an html page, and when I grab the data, I am left with this:

```
<tr>
<td class="main rank">1</td>
<td class="main company"><a href="/colleges/williams-college/">
<img alt="" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/colleges/williams-college_50x50.jpg">
<h3>Williams College</h3></img></a></td>
<td class="main">Massachusetts</td>
<td class="main">$61,850</td>
<td class="main">2,124</td>
</tr>
```

This is the beautifulsoup command I am using to get this:

```
html = open('collegelist.html')
test = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup = test.find_all('tr')
```

I now want to manipulate this text so that it outputs

```
1
Williams College
Massachusetts
$62,850
2,214
```

and I having difficulty doing so for the entire document, where I have about 700 of these entries. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the [`.text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) (or use `get_text()`) for every `tr` in the loop:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('collegelist.html'))
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print tr.text  # or tr.get_text()
```

For the HTML you've provided it prints:

```
1


Williams College
Massachusetts
$61,850
2,124
```

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I didn't see that option. Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

use `get_text()`

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
 "".join([x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all('tr')])
```